# Creating my own redirect and duplicate pipe functions

Tags: c, pipe

I am making a small shell and I am having some problems with two of my functions.
They are kind of out of context but I hope you can understand what I am trying to do so I don't have to post my whole code.

My dupPipe function:
I want to duplicate a pipe to a std I/O file descriptor and close both of the pipe ends. It looks like this: `int dupPipe(int pip[2], int end, int destinfd);`. Where end tells which pipe to duplicate, either READ_END or WRITE_END and destinfd tells which std I/O file descriptor to replace.

My Redirect function:
It's supposed to redirect a std I/O file descriptor to a file.
It looks like this, `int redirect(char *file, int flag, int destinfd);`.
Where flag indicate if the file should be read from or written to and destinfd is the std I/O file descriptor I want to redirect.

What I have done:

```
int dupPipe(int pip[2], int end, int destinfd)
{
if(end == READ_END)
{
    dup2(pip[0], destinfd);
    close(pip[0]);
}
else if(end == WRITE_END)
{
    dup2(pip[1], destinfd);
    close(pip[1]);
}
return destinfd;
}
```

Second function:

```
int redirect(char *filename, int flags, int destinfd)
{
if(flags == 0)
{
    return destinfd;
}
else if(flags == 1)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
    if(! f)
    {
        perror(filename);
        return -1;
    }
}
else if(flags == 2)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(! f)
    {
        perror(filename);
        return -1;
    }
}
return destinfd;
}
```

I appreciate any help given, what have I done wrong or haven't done with the function that I wrote wanted to? Thanks.

Comment: is destfd == destinfd?

Comment: You don't use dup2 return and you should use "open" function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `redirect` function doesn't appear to be doing what you want.  You're opening a file using `fopen`, but you're not linking it to `destinfd` in any way.  You probably want to use `open` instead, then use `dup2` to move the file descriptor to where you want.

```
int redirect(char *filename, int flags, int destinfd)
{
    int newfd;

    if(flags == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if(flags == 1) {
        newfd = open(filename, O_WRONLY);
        if (newfd == -1) {
            perror("open for write failed");
            return -1;
        }
    } else if(flags == 2) {
        newfd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
        if (newfd == -1) {
            perror("open for read failed");
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
    if (dup2(newfd, destinfd) == -1) {
        perror("dup2 failed");
        close(newfd);
        return -1;
    }
    close(newfd);
    return destinfd;
}
```

Comment: When `dup2(2)` fails, the code that handles the error should close `newfd` before returning to avoid "leaking" open file descriptors on error conditions. Note that `close(2)` may change the value of `errno`, so you should store it beforehand and then restore it before returning. OTOH, if `dup2(2)` succeeds, then you should close `newfd` if it is different from `destinfd`, or else `redirect()` will again leave an open file descriptor every time it is called.

Comment: But the newfd doesn't differ from destinfd, the "flags" variable stops it from happening right?

Comment: @Fjodor After a successful call to `dup2()`, `newfd` and `destinfd` refer to the same open file even though their values differ.  As Filipe said, `newfd` needs to be closed after the `dup2()` call.  I've also updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @dbush Hey, I know this is solved but I have a follow up problem concerning the file descriptors... I would really appreciate if you could take a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519435/program-stuck-pipe-file-descriptor-open-when-shouldnt/31521084#31521084  Thanks.