# Program stuck, pipe file descriptor open when shouldn't?

Tags: c, pipe, file-descriptor, filehandle

I am creating a small shell that can read commands. When I run my program and type:`"cat file.txt > file2.txt"` it creates the file and then it gets stuck at the line: `if(execvp(structVariables->argv[0], argv) < 0).` (waiting for input/output??). If I end the program with ctrl + d I can see in my folder that the file is created but nothing has been written in it. (dupPipe is used to handle more commands, not yet used because of problem described above)

```
if((pid = fork()) < 0)
{
        perror("fork error");
}
else if(pid > 0)        // Parent
{
        if(waitpid(pid,NULL,0) < 0)
        {
                perror("waitpid error");
        }
}
else                    // Child
{    
        int flags = 0;

        if(structVariables->outfile != NULL)
        {
                flags = 1;      // Write
                redirect(structVariables->outfile, flags, STDOUT_FILENO);
        }
        if(structVariables->infile != NULL)
        {
                flags = 2;      // Read
                redirect(structVariables->infile, flags, STDIN_FILENO);
        }

        if(execvp(structVariables->argv[0], argv) < 0)
        {
                perror("execvp error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}
```

The two functions I use in my program looks like this:
dupPipe and redirect

```
int dupPipe(int pip[2], int end, int destinfd)
{
    if(end == READ_END)
    {
       dup2(pip[0], destinfd);
       close(pip[0]);
    }
    else if(end == WRITE_END)
    {
       dup2(pip[1], destinfd);
       close(pip[1]);
    }

    return destinfd;
}

int redirect(char *filename, int flags, int destinfd)
{
        int newfd;

        if(flags == 1)
        {
                if(access(filename, F_OK) != -1)        // If file already exists
                {
                        errno = EEXIST;
                        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        return -1;
                }

                newfd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
                if(newfd == -1)
                {
                        perror("Open for write failed");
                        return -1;
                }
        }
        else if(flags == 2)
        {
                newfd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
                if(newfd == -1)
                {
                        perror("Open for read failed");
                        return -1;
                }
        }
        else
                return -1;

        if(dup2(newfd, destinfd) == -1)
        {
                perror("dup2 failed");
                close(newfd);
                return -1;
        }
        if(newfd != destinfd)
        {
                close(newfd);
        }

        return destinfd;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do.  Please post the full code, a sample of how it's called, and exactly what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to code a shell to run commands read from input (if this is not the case; please edit your question, as it is not clear).

I am not sure why you think pipes are used in a command like `cat file.txt > file2.txt`, but in any case, they are not. Let's see what happens under the hood when you type `cat file.txt > file2.txt` in a shell like bash:

1. A child process is created where `cat(1)` will run.
2. The child process opens `file2.txt` for writing (more on this later).
3. If `open(2)` is successful, the child process duplicates the newly opened file descriptor onto `stdout` (so `stdout` will effectively point to the same file table entry as `file2.txt`).
4. `cat(1)` is executed by calling one of the seven `exec()` functions. The argument `file.txt` is passed to `cat(1)`, so `cat(1)` will open `file.txt` and read everything, copying its contents to `stdout` (which is redirected to `file2.txt`).
5. `cat(1)` finishes execution and terminates, which causes any open file descriptors to be closed and flushed. By the time `cat(1)` terminates, `file2.txt` is a copy of `file.txt`.
6. Meanwhile, the parent shell process waits for the child to terminate before printing the next prompt and waiting for more commands.

As you can see, pipes are not used in I/O redirection. Pipes are an interprocess communication mechanism used to feed the output of a process into the input of another process. You only have one process running here (`cat`), so why would you even need pipes?

This means that you should be calling `redirect()` with `STDOUT_FILENO` as `destinfd` (instead of a pipe channel) for output redirection. Similarly, input redirection should call `redirect()` with `STDIN_FILENO`. These constants are defined in `unistd.h` so make sure to include that header.

You also *probably* want to exit on the child if `exec()` failed, or else you'll be running 2 copies of the shell process.

Last but not least, you shouldn't make input or output redirection exclusive. It might be the case that the user wants both input and output redirection. So instead of `else if` when doing I/O redirection I would just use 2 independent ifs.

With that in mind, the main code you posted should look something like:

```
if((pid = fork()) < 0)
{
        perror("fork error");
}
else if(pid > 0)        // Parent
{
        if(waitpid(pid,NULL,0) < 0)
        {
                perror("waitpid error");
        }
}
else                    // Child
{    
        int flags = 0;

        if(structVariables->outfile != NULL)
        {
                flags = 1;      // Write
                // We need STDOUT_FILENO here
                redirect(structVariables->outfile, flags, STDOUT_FILENO);
        }
        if(structVariables->infile != NULL)
        {
                flags = 2;      // Read
                // Similarly, we need STDIN_FILENO here
                redirect(structVariables->infile, flags, STDIN_FILENO);
        }

        // This line changed; see updated answer below
        if(execvp(structVariables->argv[0], structVariables->argv) < 0)
        {
                perror("execvp error");
                // Terminate
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}
```

As mentioned in another answer, your `redirect()` function is prone to race conditions because there is a window of time between the file existence check and the actual file creation where another process could create the file (this is known as a TOCTTOU error: Time Of Check To Time Of Use). You should use `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` to atomically test for existence and create the file.

Another problem is that you always close `newfd`. What if `newfd` and `destinfd` happen to be the same, for some reason? Then you'll be mistakenly closing the file, because `dup2(2)` is essentially a no-op if you pass in two equal file descriptors. Even if you think this will never happen, it is always good practice to check first if the duplicated fd is different from the original fd before closing the original.

Here's the code with these issues addressed:

```
int redirect(char *filename, int flags, int destinfd)
{
        int newfd;

        if(flags == 1)
        {
                newfd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
                if(newfd == -1)
                {
                        perror("Open for write failed");
                        return -1;
                }
        }
        else if(flags == 2)
        {
                newfd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
                if(newfd == -1)
                {
                        perror("Open for read failed");
                        return -1;
                }
        }
        else
                return -1;

        if(dup2(newfd, destinfd) == -1)
        {
                perror("dup2 failed");
                close(newfd);
                return -1;
        }

        if (newfd != destinfd)
            close(newfd);

        return destinfd;
}
```

Consider replacing `0666` in `open(2)` above with `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH` (make sure to include `sys/stat.h` and `fcntl.h`). You might want to use a `#define` to make it cleaner, but I still think it's better and more descriptive if you do it like that rather than hardcoding some magic number (this is subjective though).

I won't comment on `dupPipe()` since it's not needed / used in this question. I/O redirection is all you need. If you want to extend the discussion to pipes, feel free to edit the question or create another one.

**UPDATE**

Ok, now that I had a look at the full source code, I have a couple more remarks.

The reason `cat(1)` is hanging is because of this:

```
if (execvp(structVariables->argv[0], argv) < 0)
```

The second parameter to `execvp(2)` should be `structVariables->argv`, **not** `argv`, because `argv` is the argument array of the shell program, which is (usually) empty. Passing an empty argument list to `cat(1)` makes it read from `stdin` rather than from a file, so that's why it seems to hang - it's waiting for you to feed input. So, go ahead and replace that line with:

```
if (execvp(structVariables->argv[0], structVariables->argv) < 0)
```

This solves one of your issues: things like `cat < file.txt > file2.txt` will now work (I tested it).

**About pipe redirection**

So now we need to work on pipe redirection. Pipe redirection happens every time we see `|` on the command line. Let's work through an example to understand what happens under the hood when we type `ls | grep "file.txt" | sort`. It is important to understand these steps so that you can build an accurate mental model of how the system works; without such a vision, you will not really understand the implementation:

1. The shell (typically) splits the commands by the pipe symbol first. This is also what your code does. This means that after parsing, the shell has gathered enough information and the command line was split into 3 entities (the `ls` command, the `grep` command and the `sort` command).
2. The shell forks and calls one of the seven `exec()` functions on the child to run `ls`. Now, remember that piping means that the output of a program is the input of the next, so before `exec()`ing, the shell has to create a pipe. The child process that is about to run `ls(1)` calls `dup2(2)` before `exec()` to duplicate the pipe's write channel onto `stdout`. Similarly, the parent process calls `dup2(2)` to duplicate the pipe's read channel onto `stdin`. It is very important that you understand this step: because the parent duplicate the pipe's read end to `stdin`, then whatever we do next (e.g. fork again to execute more commands) will always read input from the pipe. So, at this point, we have `ls(1)` writing to `stdout`, which is redirected to a pipe that is read by the shell's parent process.
3. The shell will now execute `grep(1)`. Again, it forks a new process to execute `grep(1)`. Remember that file descriptors are inherited across a fork, and that the parent shell's process has `stdin` tied to the read end of the pipe connected to `ls(1)`, so the new child process that is about to execute `grep(1)` will "automagically" read from that pipe! But wait, there's more! The shell knows that there is yet another process in the pipeline (the `sort` command), so before executing grep (and before forking), the shell creates *another* pipe to connect the output of `grep(1)` to the input of `sort(1)`. Then, it repeats the same steps: on the child process, the pipe's write channel is duplicated onto `stdout`. In the parent, the pipe's read channel is duplicated onto `stdin`. Again, it is important to really understand what is happening here: the process that is about to execute `grep(1)` already had its input being read from the pipe connected to `ls(1)`, and now it has the output connected to the pipe that will feed `sort(1)`. So `grep(1)` is essentially reading from a pipe and writing to a pipe. OTOH, the parent shell process duplicated the last pipe's read channel to `stdin`, effectively "giving up" from reading the output of `ls(1)` (because `grep(1)` will handle it anyway), but instead updating the input stream to read the results from `grep(1)`.
4. Finally, the shell sees that `sort(1)` is the last command, so it just forks + execs `sort(1)`. The results are written to `stdout`, because we never changed `stdout` in the shell process, but input is read from the pipe that connects `grep(1)` to `sort(1)` because of our actions in step 3.

So how is this implemented?

Simple: as long as there is more than one command left to process, we create a pipe and fork. On the child, we close the pipe's read channel, duplicate the pipe's write channel onto `stdout`, and call one of the seven `exec()` functions. On the parent, we close the pipe's write channel, and duplicate the pipe's read channel onto `stdin`.

When there is only one command left to process, we simply fork + exec, without creating a pipe.

There is only one last detail to clarify: before starting the `pipe(2)` redirection party, we need to store a reference to the original shell's standard input, since we will (possibly) change it many times throughout the way. If we didn't save it, we might lose the reference to the original `stdin` file, and then we wouldn't be able to read user input anymore! In the code, I usually do this with `fcntl(2)` with the `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` (see `man 2 fcntl`), to ensure that the descriptor is closed when a command is executed in the child process (it is usually bad practice to leave open file descriptors around when they are used).

Also, the shell process needs to `wait(2)` on the *last* process in the pipeline. If you think about it, it makes sense: pipes inherently synchronize each command in the pipeline; the set of commands is assumed to be over only when the last command reads `EOF` from the pipe (that is, we know that we're done only when all of the data flowed throughout the entire pipeline). If the shell didn't wait for the last process, but instead waited for some other process in the middle (or in the beginning) of the pipeline, it would return back to the command prompt too soon and leave other commands still running on the background - not a smart move, as the user expects the shell to finish executing the current job before waiting for more.

So ... this is a lot of information, but it is really important that you understand it. So the revised main code is here:

```
int saved_stdin = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC, 0);

if (saved_stdin < 0) {
    perror("Couldn't store stdin reference");
    break;
}

pid_t pid;
int i;
/* As long as there are at least two commands to process... */
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    /* We create a pipe to connect this command to the next command */
    int pipefds[2];

    if (pipe(pipefds) < 0) {
        perror("pipe(2) error");
        break;
    }

    /* Prepare execution on child process and make the parent read the
     * results from the pipe
     */
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork(2) error");
        break;
    }

    if (pid > 0) {
        /* Parent needs to close the pipe's write channel to make sure
         * we don't hang. Parent reads from the pipe's read channel.
         */

        if (close(pipefds[1]) < 0) {
            perror("close(2) error");
            break;
        }

        if (dupPipe(pipefds, READ_END, STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
            perror("dupPipe() error");
            break;
        }
    } else {

        int flags = 0;

        if (structVariables[i].outfile != NULL)
        {
            flags = 1;      // Write
            if (redirect(structVariables[i].outfile, flags, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0) {
                perror("redirect() error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        if (structVariables[i].infile != NULL)
        {
            flags = 2;      // Read
            if (redirect(structVariables[i].infile, flags, STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
                perror("redirect() error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        /* Child writes to the pipe (that is read by the parent); the read
         * channel doesn't have to be closed, but we close it for good practice
         */

        if (close(pipefds[0]) < 0) {
            perror("close(2) error");
            break;
        }

        if (dupPipe(pipefds, WRITE_END, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0) {
            perror("dupPipe() error");
            break;
        }

        if (execvp(structVariables[i].argv[0], structVariables[i].argv) < 0) {
            perror("execvp(3) error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

if (i != n-1) {
    /* Some error caused an early loop exit */
    break;
}

/* We don't need a pipe for the last command */
if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("fork(2) error on last command");
}

if (pid > 0) {
    /* Parent waits for the last command to execute */
    if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        perror("waitpid(2) error");
    }
} else {
    int flags = 0;
    /* Execute last command. This will read from the last pipe we set up */
    if (structVariables[i].outfile != NULL)
    {
        flags = 1;      // Write
        if (redirect(structVariables[i].outfile, flags, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0) {
            perror("redirect() error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    if (structVariables[i].infile != NULL)
    {
        flags = 2;      // Read
        if (redirect(structVariables[i].infile, flags, STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
            perror("redirect() error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    if (execvp(structVariables[i].argv[0], structVariables[i].argv) < 0) {
        perror("execvp(3) error on last command");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/* Finally, we need to restore the original stdin descriptor */
if (dup2(saved_stdin, STDIN_FILENO) < 0) {
    perror("dup2(2) error when attempting to restore stdin");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (close(saved_stdin) < 0) {
    perror("close(2) failed on saved_stdin");
}
```

Some final remarks about `dupPipe()`:

- Both `dup2(2)` and `close(2)` may return an error; you should probably check for this and act accordingly (i.e. pass the error up the call stack by returning -1).
- Again, you shouldn't blindly close the descriptor after you duplicate it, because it may be the case that the source and destination descriptors are the same.
- You should validate that `end` is either `READ_END` or `WRITE_END`, and return an error if that is not true (instead of returning `destinfd` no matter what, which may give a false sense of success to the caller code)

Here's how I would improve it:

```
int dupPipe(int pip[2], int end, int destinfd)
{
    if (end != READ_END && end != WRITE_END)
        return -1;

    if(end == READ_END)
    {
        if (dup2(pip[0], destinfd) < 0)
            return -1;
        if (pip[0] != destinfd && close(pip[0]) < 0)
            return -1;
    }
    else if(end == WRITE_END)
    {
        if (dup2(pip[1], destinfd) < 0)
            return -1;
        if (pip[1] != destinfd && close(pip[1]) < 0)
            return -1;
    }

    return destinfd;
}
```

Have fun with your shell!

Comment: The idea is that I am supposed to be able to type ex: cat file.txt | tail -5 > file2.txt. But I found out it didn't work even if I wrote cat file.txt > file2.txt so that's why pipes aren't needed (yet). Anyhow thanks for answering! I updated my code according to what you type and I see where I did wrong but it still doesn't work... the program still gets stuck while executing execvp. I then use ctrl + d and look for the file and it has in fact been created. There's just nothing in it. Can you find something else that is wrong?

Comment: @Fjodor but does it work with `cat file.txt > file2.txt` now? I need to know if this issue is solved before we talk about pipes.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. The problem is still there, but I understand why I shouldn't involve the pipes just yet. So no, cat file.txt > file2.txt just puts the program "on hold". But as I mentioned, I can find the file in my folder but I have to exit the program with ctrl + d.

Comment: @Fjodor That's odd. Could you please update your question and add all of the code so I can compile it here? There may be something wrong in `structVariables` or in the way you parse commands. Show me the whole code.

Comment: This is an assignment I'm working on where I got the parse code for free so I can assure there's nothing wrong with that. If you want to compile the code can I send you the code on an email or something so I don't have to spend a lot of time putting it here and flooding the Q? But as I said, pretty sure the parsing isn't the problem

Comment: @Fjodor Well I'm not saying it's the parsing code, my point is that some *other* part of the code that you think is ok may have some bug whose effects become visible much later in the program. Feel free to e-mail me the code and I'll be happy to look into this for you (and I'll update my answer). Check my profile to get my address.

Comment: Okay, I've sent the files now. Thanks for taking your time with this! I appreciate it.

Comment: @Fjodor See updated answer (after "UPDATE") for a detailed explanation of what was happening and how pipe redirection works.

Answer (score 2):

execvp does not return unless there is an error.

Therefore, the originating program will (normally) not execute code beyond the call to execvp()

the normal sequence of code is:

```
1) fork()
2) if child then call execvp(); 
3) if parent ....
```

Comment: I don't see why placing parent being after or before child would help me in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `open()` incorrectly in `redirect()` if `flags == 1`:

```
    if(flags == 1)
    {
            if(access(filename, F_OK) != -1)        // If file already exists
            {
                    errno = EEXIST;
                    printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
            }
            newfd = open(filename, O_CREAT, O_WRONLY);
            if(newfd == -1)
            {
                    perror("Open for write failed");
                    return -1;
            }
    }
```

In `newfd = open(filename, O_CREAT, O_WRONLY);`, `O_WRONLY` is (incorrectly) used in place of the `mode` argument to `open()`, rather than or'd in the `flags`:

```
    if(flags == 1)
    {
            if(access(filename, F_OK) != -1)        // If file already exists
            {
                    errno = EEXIST;
                    printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
            }
            newfd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, mode); //whatever mode you want, but remember umask.
            if(newfd == -1)
            {
                    perror("Open for write failed");
                    return -1;
            }
    }
```

Also, the check for the previous existence of the file is racy, another program can create the file after the `access()` and before the `open()`. Use `open(filename, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, mode)` to atomically create and open a file.

Comment: I've created a mode but I am unsure on how to use umask, do I just call it afterwards?

Comment: If you want to change your process' file-creation mask, you need to call `umask()` *before* the `open()/creat()`. You should read the manpage for `umask()` if you don't know what to do, but if you're in a hurry you could just call `umask(0)`, in which case the `mode` argument to `open()` will be used unmodified.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it by typing 0666 in open(3). It works now when I want to open the file after it has been created. However there's nothing in the file... which indicates that there's something wrong with the piping? I can't find the solution...

Comment: Yes, a newly created file is empty. You're going to have to be a bit more specific about your problem. What do you *want* the code to do, what *does* it do, what is the relevant code?

Comment: What I'm saying is, I am using the command "cat myFile.c" (already existed file with code in it) but it doesn't print out anything (while I am in my shell). And the program gets hung up at the execvp line... accoding to other threads on the internet the problem appears when file descriptors aren't opened and closed correctly. So what I'm wondering is if you can see what's wrong because I've been looking at it for some time now. The relevant code is everything except what's in function "redirect" because it will never enter there if I only type "cat myFile.c".

Comment: The code you've posted makes little sense as it is: There is no pipe in IO-redirection to a file. Also, why do you `redirect()` to the same `fd[0]` twice? Why do you not redirect to `STDIN_FILENO/STDOUT_FILENO`?

Comment: I asked this question to get to know what I've done wrong and get a better understanding of how this works so I assumed that my code "made little sense". About the "no pipe in IO re.." I will try to fix but please me more detailed in how in how it should work. "why do you redirect..." I changed the if + if statements to if + if else, they cannot happen at the same time. And as to your last question, I don't know, as I said I am trying to figure out but gotten confused with pipes...